# Shape Pattern Matching Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching, gesture, gesture-recognition

I'm looking for a Java implementations of shape matching algorithms.
here's an image to demonstrate of what i had in mind :

[image]

I would also be interested to know if there are any good free implementations of**gestures recognition** for Android

Comment: I've voted to close as "not constructive". [Shopping list questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) are discouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DuncanJones let me know what details are missing. i don't see how is this a "shopping list question".

Comment: Maybe you should ask what algorithms do exist. If you know the algorithms than you can easily find existing implementations or make one of your own.

Comment: @Pavel'PK'Kaminsky You've requested links to existing implementations for Android. AIUI, that's the classic shopping list question and suffers from the problems listed in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [eclipse sketch](http://www.eclipse.org/sketch/). There's a video on the page demonstrating the use of it and how it works. Sketch is doing gesture recognition for use in graphical editors. The implementation is not intended to run on android, but maybe you can learn from it.